# React-Navigation this.props.navigation.navigate undefined is not an object

Tags: react-native

I am using react-navigation but my codes return ; this undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this2.props.navigation.navigate)

how can i fix this error?

myCodes;

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import Login from './components/LoginScreen/LoginScreen';
    import AddNewUser from './components/AddNewUserScreen/AddNewUserScreen';
    import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

    class App extends Component{
        render(){
            return(
                <Login />
            );
        }


    }

    const RootStack = ({ createStackNavigator }) => (
        {
          Login: Login,
          AddNew: AddNewUser,
        });

    export default App;
```

LoginScreen.js

```
 <TouchableOpacity style={styles.ButtonContainer} onPress={()=> this.props.navigation.navigate('AddNew')}>
<Text style={styles.buttonText} >GİRİŞ</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: where are you using `const RootStack` ?

Comment: nowhere.........

Comment: that is the problem, you need to use `RootStack` , as you have made a variable of it, but not using it anywhere, which means it wont be used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should start your app by calling `RootStack`  like this:

```
class App extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <RootStack />
        );
    }
}
```

also you can set initialRout in stack like this:

```
const RootStack = createStackNavigator({
      Login: Login,
      AddNew: AddNewUser,
}, { initialRouteName: 'Login'} )
```

Now, as you define, your app will start with login page and it has `this.props.navigation` by itself so you can use `this.props.navigation.navigate('AddNew')` without error. 
But if you need to use navigation from a component, you have to send `this.props.navigation` from parent to component like this:

```
<YourComponent navigation={this.props.navigation}/>
```

Then you can use navigation in `YourComponent` component.
I hope this can help you

Comment: I changed my code as you said , but error still continue

Comment: Thank you :) okey than now I take warning : isMounted(...) how can i solve it :D

Comment: its a common warning :-D I just ignore it by adding `YellowBox.ignoreWarnings(['Warning: isMounted(...) is deprecated', 'Module RCTImageLoader']);` in constructor of your first page and import `YellowBox` from react native. (for RN>54 i think!)